# How to execute jquery code for webview by java?

Tags: java, android, jquery, webview

I want execute a jquery on webview.I fill webview with a html  file. and wrote in oncreate method this codes :

```
WebView wv=new WebView(this);
    setContentView(wv);

           WebSettings webViewSettings = wv.getSettings();
           webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           webViewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);            
           wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); 
    wv.loadUrl("javascript:fill()");
```

and add to oncreate method this attribute : `@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")`

My html file :

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script >
function fill(){
$('#input1').val('123');
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
<input type="text"  id="input1"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I test my jquery code in chrome and worked . but when run app don't worked. Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadUrl()` is asynchronous; it will return but the content will not have finished loading (including your `fill()` javascript method) before you try to invoke `fill()` on the next line. Try adding a listener for when the page has finished loading and invoke the javascript method from there:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:fill()");
    }
});
```

Comment: I should write this  listener  in oncreate method ?

Comment: just put it before you do `wv.loadUrl()`

Comment: glad I could help :)